# Can i rename "delta" value in Drupal blocks?

Tags: drupal, rename, delta

When i add a display in a view, and i display this as a block, drupal generates a delta value like this: 3429ef48c33321bf7e5eb0c441c9f540 and i would like to rename this for something more simply.

I juts modify delta value directly in blocks table, but my block-views-[delta-value].tpl is not displaying.

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an other option to add a tpl for a views display

Refer here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWEQH.png)

---

http://drupal.org/user/1313260